# Android speech recognition for non-dictionary words

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am developing an Android application of speech recognition for non-dictionary words. I want to remove the dictionary and do it for any word. 
For example If I pronounce word "pini", my current application get it as "beanie". I want the word to recognize as it is pronounced.

My code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnSpeak:
        promptSpeechInput();
        break;}
}

@Override
// act on result of TTS data check
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent
                    .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
    // Receiving speech input
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}
@Override
// act on result of TTS data check
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent
                    .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
    // Receiving speech input
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}

public void speakWords(String speech) {
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

/**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 * */
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use the phonetic similarity algorithm provided by apache commons to check the phonetic similarity between the recognized word and non-dictionary word. If there's a similarity you display the non-dictionary word.

Comment: @SamuelGhartey Isn't there a way to remove dictionary and get the exact word without mapping it with a dictionary word?

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible